# parsing urls from array instance to cURL and get data

Tags: arrays, bash, curl

I need to parse links from an `array[0]` - `array[3]` which are all URLs and send to a for loop which is cURL and will download the html and shoot it too another array. Getting the error `no URL specified!`

```
echo "${array[0]}"

for i in ${array[@]}
do
   dataset=($(curl -d \ $i))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things, the `-d` is a post and you indicated you wanted to download.  Appending to arrays is as easy as `+=()`.  You can do something like this:

```
dataset=()
for i in ${array[@]}
do
   dataset+=($(curl --silent $i))
done
```